# Terminal Autocomplete and History does not work

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, auto-completion

I am a Mac user who has recently switched to Lubuntu on my personal laptop. The issue I'm facing is that my terminal does not do any sort of autocomplete or show history. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> just adds a tab and pressing the <kbd>Up</kbd> button shows the escaped character `^[[A`

e.g. if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `apt-g`, I just get `apt-g` with some spaces after

I've tried on the default `qterminal` and on `guake`, and checked terminal preferences

Comment: Do you have `bash-completion` (package) installed?  *Providing the release may have helped, I'd have done more searching, as my Lubuntu sure has it - I'd miss it terribly*

Comment: You also might want to clarify what you mean by `history` ; if you type `history` into a terminal, do you not get a list of your prior commands?  or only some commands? or do you mean the <UP/DOWN> arrows whilst trying commands (myself: my profile doesn't store all commands in my `history` which I prefer; when I logged in local but not if I remotely login.. This can be changed - but your question was vague)

Comment: I think he means the up/down arrows